# Hardware can do different tasks - how to tell software?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

imagine a robot that is capable of performing several different, completely independent tasks. The only relation between the tasks is that they are all within a statically defined environment at known locations.

The hardware is designed to drive to the task locations and, using servos and steppers for example, perform the given task.

What's the best way to, using ROS, build up the node graph? What kind of nodes do I need besides the basic lowlevel controlling nodes for each hardware component? What needs to be built on top of that?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69277/hardware-can-do-different-tasks---how-to-tell-software?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-26**:
Check out Martin's answer to my similar question from a long time ago: http://answers.ros.org/question/12182/controllers-vs-drivers/

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-07-26**:
That's interesting as well. Will look into it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you heard Smach? http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach
If I understand correctly, this may be what you are looking for.

Some terms may be different than what you are used to but see if you can define your nodes as states and turn them into state machines by adding transitions.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-07-26**:
That looks really promising at the first glance. I'll have a look at it. Thanks so far!